# 1983 22R Randomly started sounding like a chopped harley

Tags: toyota, exhaust

5 second videos, this is what it sounded like:

Yesterday: http://youtu.be/_2Nl0bR1QOA

and

Today: http://youtu.be/zP4_cT8yaH4

- It sounds like this regardless of engine temp
- Started randomly
- It's now hard to start, takes 6-8 cranks, struggles to get up to idle, whereas before it would crank once, the engine would sound like it was exploding and start right up

I'm leaving out details to be concise and considerate, please believe me when I say that I am very meticulous and methodical and have checked these things properly, per my noggin/real-deal FSM:

- Timing is @ factory spec
- Valve clearances @ factory spec
- Timing chain, tensioner and guides are good
- All wire/plugs are receiving voltage
- Advancing/retarding timing does not change new noisiness
- Oil & coolant are clean
- Exhaust fumes are not visible, colored, do not smell like oil/antifreeze
- No vacuum leaks on head, intake manifold, or carb adapter (checked w/ propane)

  - Manifold vacuum holds ~18psi (factory spec) at idle
- Weber tuning reset to baseline, no change
- No change in noise from choke opening/closing
- Gas is clean, fuel filters clear
- Float bowl of weber is clean, float level correct, fuel pressure correct
- New harmonic balancer & water pump <100mi ago
- All seals checked & good, no leaking oil/coolant
- Only one tiny exhaust leak present - I checked with soapy water and also a microphone (15 sec video: http://youtu.be/bMWS-Xmfc-4)

  - Exhaust popping/crackling under load when coming off of the gas quickly, no popping/crackling when revving down in neutral

Comment: Great first question! Judging by the plug wire vibrations, something's not right with at least one of the cylinders. It might be an idea to measure the exhaust manifold temperatures using a laser thermometer to help you locate where the problem is occurring

Comment: @Zaid I think I found the issue. There's a gap in the exhaust manifold by cylinder #4 and a missing bolt. It looks like the previous owner tried to seal it by mixing gorilla glue and high temp RTV. Thank you for the reply and suggestion :)

Comment: Great! It would help if you post up what you found as an answer along with pictures.